# How to extract a substring between two characters in a string having undetermined pattern in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have read a lot of topics discussing extracting substring between two characters but my problem is a bit different than the existing ones. I have a string like this with different patterns
'''
/m/ hello end; /r/ how are you end;
'''

I need to separate strings between /m/ and end; and between /r/ and end;

I have used substring and charindex functions which give correct output BUT NOT in all cases of input string. My input string has too many variation .e.g. it could be like
'''
/m/ hello /r/ how are you end;       (no end in /m/ part)
'''
in this case if I extract string between /m/ and end; it will include /r/ which I don't need. if I change the logic and extract between /m/ and /r/ then /r/ could be before /m/ e.g.

'''
/r/ I am working from home during this pandemic end; /m/ how about you end;  /r/ before /m/)
'''
input string has nor definite length.

Tried to use PATINDEX but my input string has no specific pattern.

I need expert's advice.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Based on the mention of `patindex()`, I changed the tags to sql-server.  Clear sample data and desired results would really help.  Are you looking for one result or multiple results?

Comment: Thanks. I need multiple results. I separated the strings using union operator. sample data.'/m/ orders due'/r/don't expect it early end;' desired- two separate lines '/m/ orders due' and '/r/don't expect it early' but sometimes input could be' /r/we are closed end;/m/we are not expecting new orders end;' but sometimes end; exists sometimes not in the input string. desired result two lines '/m/we are closed' and '/r/we are not expecting new orders end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This splits the string by replacing both /m/ and /r/ with a pipe '|' and then using STRING_SPLIT on the result.

```
declare @string         varchar(100)=''' /m/ hello end; /r/ how are you end; ''';

select @string=replace(@string, t.v, '|')
from
  (values ('/m/'), ('/r/')) t(v);

select trim([value]) split_string from string_split(@string, '|');
```

UPDATED:  To retain the two search terms inside @string it uses nested REPLACE functions.  To retain the ordering of the appearance of the search terms I used [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) splitter.

```
declare @string         varchar(100)=''' /m/ hello end; /r/ how are you end; ''';

select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(replace(replace(@string,'/m/', '|/m/'),'/r/', '|/r/'), '|');
```

Comment: Thanks Steve!But I need to know which sting part is /m/ and which is /r/. As in the next column I have to set string typr base on the tags /m/ and /r/ e.g. '/m/ hello end;   mtype' and next line '/r/ how are you end;    rtype'. Any suggestion please?